# How to improve loading time of 'query.mobile'

Tags: javascript, android, performance, jquery-mobile, lazy-loading

I am developing a mobile App (Android) based on jq and jq mobile. I tried to reduce the time required to start the app as much as possible (e.g. many things are done in the background). All css/js/html pages are included in the App (not loaded via the network).

I recognized that a significant time is required just to load & process the jquery-mobile js file (S3 around 800-900ms, Netbook (intel Atom, 1.6GHz) 500ms).

Certainly the files size of the jquery-mobile.js is quite large, but if I simply compare the loading time & file size of my scripts and jqm, jqm requires magnitues more time (just bytes/seconds).

Therefore, I assume that after the loading already "something" is done...

Is there any way to reduce the loading/processing time of the jqm-js file (without using customer build jq-mobile version)?

Source code:

```
webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
settings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+packageName+"/databases");
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setUserAgentString(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "jsinterface");
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

What is large:

jqmobile library has arround 200k and the loading/processing time is around 800ms (Samsung S3). My modules have e.g. a size of 81k and the loading time is 40-50ms

Even if the jq-mobile code might be ultra efficient (since developed by experts), I do not understand the difference. All *.js files are loaded in the same way:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("src", fname+"?id="+rnd_num);
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("language", "javascript");
document.getElementById('id_head').appendChild(script);
```

Any ideas?

Using a customized version might be reduce the loading time a bit, but I cannot believe that something like <100ms can be achieved.

Comment: How much is "quite large"?

Comment: Do you have your code of your `WebView` where you are loading your webPage?

Comment: If you think the js file is too big, then customize it using the builder and stip off parts you don't need or using. --- http://jquerymobile.com/download/